# What is the alternate way of doing "add" and "carry" operation in Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, carryflag

Hye! I have a question regarding Assembly Language.
The instruction `adc eax, ebx` adds register `eax`, register `ebx`, and the contents of the carry flag, and then store the result back to `eax`. My question is that assume `adc` instructions are not allowed, then how can we write instructions that produce the exact same behaviour as `adc eax, ebx`.

I have written some code below but probably not correct.

```
   add eax, ebx
   add eax, 1
```

Comment: That would not be correct. Adding carry doesn't always add 1, that depends on the value of the carry flag.

Comment: *exact* same behaviour?  Do you also need to produce the same FLAGS *results* that `adc` would, at least for the carry-out CF result?  Because that's harder.  Producing just the right EAX result (EAX + EBX + CF) can be done with 2x LEA + CMOVC, setc + movzx + 2x add, or LEA + a conditional branch over an INC, or various other ways.

Comment: I have to break the code : adc eax, ebx into simple instructions in which I should not use "adc".

Comment: Only 20 minutes left for submission! I don't know from where do they get these weird quesitons.

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanAli You can use `jc` to conditionally jump depending on whether the carry flag is set or not.  Use this to do one thing if it is set and another if it is not.

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanAli Also, I really hope this is not an exam.  Do not cheat!

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanAli: The result must depend on the carry flag, so the code must have  something that is influenced by carry flag (e.g. maybe one of `jc`, `jnc`, `rcl`, `rcr`, `sbb`, ..).

Comment: Its an assignment!

Comment: add eax , ebx and then check the carry with jc , then jump to L1 and add 1 to eax register else add 0 to eax register

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is use conditional jumps to handle the carry flag. There are probably a few ways you can go about this. Here is my approach:

```
    push ebx             ; We want to preserve ebx. This seems lazy but it's
                         ; an easy approach.

    jnc carry_handled    ; If the carry is set:
    add ebx, 1           ;   Add 1 to summand. We are using
                         ;   ADD here, because INC does not
                         ;   set the carry flag.
                         ;
    jz carry_overflowed  ;   If it overflows (ebx is 0), then
                         ;   skip the addition. We don't want
                         ;   to add 0 which will clear the
                         ;   carry flag.
carry_handled:           ; 
    add eax, ebx         ; Add the adjusted summand.
carry_overflowed:
    pop ebx
```

The important thing to look out for is that you want the CPU flags to be correctly set just the same as if an `adc` was executed. In the above approach, the `jz carry_overflowed` is excess if you don't care about the carry flag afterwards.